# CSS positioning images on top of eacother and make center bar

Tags: css, image, internet-explorer, position, center

Hey guys I simply cannot get this to work.

I have some content that is centred on the page using the margin: auto; "trick".

In this content I have an image. I need to make a color bar coming under the image continuing out to the sides of the browser. On the right side I need it to look like its coming up onto the image.

I have made this picture to try an graphically show what I mean: [image](http://ronnie-jespersen.dk/help.png)

As you can see the bar runs from the left to the right side of the browser. The centred image is just placed on top of it and then an image positioned on the top of the image. But I haven't been able to get this working. Any one who would give it a go?

I tried positioning the bar relative and z-index low. This worked but the bar keep jumping around in IE 7-8-9. Centring the image wasn't easy either and placing that smaller image on top was even harder. It wouldn't follow the browser if you resized it. The problem here is that the user have to be able to upload a new picture so I cant just make a static image.

Please help I am really lost here

EDIT:

Tried the example below but when I run the site in IE 7-8-9 I have different results. [link](http://ronnie-jespersen.dk/test/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made a jsFiddle which should work in Chrome and IE7-9: http://jsfiddle.net/7gaE9/

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
<div id="bar1"></div>
<img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300"/>
<div id="bar2"></div>
</div>​
```

**CSS**

```
#container{
   width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;   
    background-color: red;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}
#bar1{
    background-color: blue;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    height: 30px;
    width: 40%;
}
#bar2{
    background-color: blue;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 3;
    height: 30px;
    width: 40%;
    position: absolute;
}
img{
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 2;
    position: relative;
}
​
​
```

The key here is that the container is positioned relative, thus enabling absolute positioning of the child elements in relation to their parent. Use z-index to control how the elements are stacked.

Comment: This does look very promising. Although when I try and implement the code in my solutions I again have different results in different browsers. Not when I try your code alone.

Comment: I have edited the description in the top there is a link to my try with you method

Comment: I won't be able to test in IE until tomorrow, but you should try to put the bar inside the container (make it full width). Now, you're not actually using #bar1 for anything.

Comment: Jørgen havde you been able to look into it? I cant seem to get it working... Dont know why this is so hard to obtain :S

Comment: I think your solution would be much less complicated if you have the container take the full page width. Then you won't have to align the outer bar with the inner. I guess that's what's causing you trouble.

Comment: Hmm not sure I know what you mean... I want the content to be centered in the middle and the container does have width: 100%; Its almost working right now but the bars dosent align in firefox ie7-8-9. Its placed in different places every time

Comment: Its working now besides an odd thing. In firefox I need top: 38% but in all IE and chrom I need 38.5% to align the content perfectly.

Comment: If your bar is 100px high, you could set top: 50%; and margin-top: -50px; Can you try that?

Comment: Jørgen could you check the link again http://ronnie-jespersen.dk/test/ I have uploaded the new version... you might be better off looking at that one :) Thanks

Comment: Your container is only 900px wide. It has to be 100%. Skip the #bar element, and let #bar1 and #bar2 go all the way to each end.

Answer (score -2):

A method I use for centering anything with css is:

```
    .yourclass {
    width:500px;
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:50%;
    left:-250px;
    }
```

'left' must be have of your width and then make it negative.
To date I have not experienced any problems with this.

Comment: This is only useful for centering absolutely positioned elements, which should only be used in the right circumstances. Using absolute positioning just for centering will cause a world of pain.

Comment: oh okay... what do you recommend then?

Comment: Well, if it's an inline element, text-align: center on the parent will work. If it's block level margin: 0 auto; This isn't what he is trying to achieve though if you read the question, Jørgen's solution works.

Comment: I'm sorry, I misread it, I'll read more carefully in the future.